# how to find list of childs nodes in a single query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I have below table.

```
Create table ParentChildhierarchy (Parent varchar(50),Child varchar(50))
```

In this table I have inserted few rows using below SQL script.

```
insert into ParentChildhierarchy values('A','B')

insert into ParentChildhierarchy values('B','C')

insert into ParentChildhierarchy values('C','D')

insert into ParentChildhierarchy values('E','A')

insert into ParentChildhierarchy values('F','K')
```

Now i need a single line query which can give me list of all child nodes. for example, For Parent "A" , it should list down "B,C,D". for Parent "B", it should list down "C,D" for parent "C", it should list down "D" for parent "D", it should list down "Null" for parent "E", it should list down "A" for parent "F", it should list down "K"

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL server 2008 and SQL 2012

Answer (score 6):

Use recursive query :

```
DECLARE @Parent VARCHAR(50) = 'A'
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy
         WHERE  parent = @Parent 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.*
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy a
                JOIN cte b
                  ON a.parent = b.child)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

UPDATE :
below query will concat the result :

```
DECLARE @Parent VARCHAR(50) = 'A'
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy
         WHERE  parent = @Parent 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.*
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy a
                JOIN cte b
                  ON a.parent = b.child)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Child
              FROM   cte
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16a6f/6)

UPDATE 2 :

for all the row :

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Parent [TopParent]
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy
         --WHERE  Parent = 'A'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.*,
                [TopParent]
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy a
                JOIN cte b
                  ON a.parent = b.child)
SELECT [TopParent],
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + Child
              FROM   cte b
              WHERE  a.[TopParent] = b.[TopParent]
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM   cte a
GROUP  BY [TopParent]
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16a6f/11)

all the rows with those which don't have a child :

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Parent [TopParent]
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy
         --WHERE  Parent = 'A'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.*,
                [TopParent]
         FROM   ParentChildhierarchy a
                JOIN cte b
                  ON a.parent = b.child) SELECT [TopParent],
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + Child
              FROM   cte b
              WHERE  a.[TopParent] = b.[TopParent]
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM   cte a
GROUP  BY [TopParent]
UNION
SELECT Child,
       NULL
FROM   ParentChildhierarchy p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   ParentChildhierarchy c
                   WHERE  p.Child = c.Parent)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16a6f/13)

Check this Microsoft documentation on Recursive query : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: i think you haven't read the question properly. A has B as child and B has C as child and C has D as a child hence against A we need to show B,C,D all the child nodes. not only the immediate node but also all child nodes in the series.

Comment: did you mean that you need it in a string format ? like `B,C,D` in a single result field separated by commas?

Comment: This is returning the desired result, only thing left is that parent "A" is hardcoded while we need to  return all parent and against all parent we need to display all childs.

Comment: check Update 2 if helps.